# Is Python class variable static?

Tags: python, class

Seeing the following code:

```
class Super:
    powers = 'no power'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_power(self, power):
        self.powers = power

dog = Super('dog')
cat = Super('cat')

dog.add_power("bark")
print (dog.powers) # print bark
print (cat.powers) # print no power
```

it looks like python's class variable is independent to each instance because change dog instance's `powers` variable from no power to bark does not affect the cat instance's `powers` variable

However, by doing this:

```
class Super:
    powers = ["no power"]
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_power(self, power):
        self.powers.append(power) 

dog = Super('dog')
cat = Super('cat')

dog.add_power("bark")
print (dog.powers) # print ['no power', 'bark']
print (cat.powers) # print ['no power', 'bark']  # why cat.powers is also affected???
```

The example shows powers variable (it is a list this time) is static since append an element to dog instance's `powers` also affects cat instance's `powers`.

I also experimented with changing the powers to an int and increment powers by 1 by calling add_power, and they don't affect each other. So I am really confused why appending an element to a list which is a class variable affects other instances.

Comment: Related:  [How to specify a variable as a member variables of a class or of an instance of the class?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39108996/674039)

Comment: The difference is the top one is using and **replacing** a class string, and the bottom is using and **appending** a class list: just because you added something to the class list via `dog` doesn't make it not a class list.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An instance variable name can *shadow* a class variable of the same name.

```
>>> class A:
...     var = 'class var'
...     
>>> a = A()
>>> vars(a)  # no instance variables
{}
>>> a.var  # attribute lookup resolved at the class level
'class var'
>>> a.var = 'instance var'  # create an instance variable
>>> vars(a)  # the name `var` now exists in the instance dict
{'var': 'instance var'}
>>> a.var  # attribute lookup resolved at the instance level
'instance var'
>>> type(a).var  # note: the class variable still exists!
'class var'
>>> del a.var  # deletes from the instance dict
>>> a.var  # ..but the name `var` remains available at the class level
'class var'
>>> vars(a)  # instance dict is again empty
{}
```

It's not the case that the class variable is "static" (`A.var` can be modified or deleted via normal attribute access).  What's happening instead is: accessing `a.var` first tries the name `var` in the instance's namespace (`a.__dict__`), and if that fails then the lookup falls back to checking in the class's namespace (`A.__dict__`).

The reason  you don't see the same behaviour when using a list on the class object is that **this line is not an [assignment statement](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment)**:

```
self.powers.append(power)
```

A seemingly equivalent version which is using an assignment statement *would* recreate the same name shadowing that you observed:

```
self.powers = self.powers + [power]  # not actually equivalent!
```

In summary: when using an integer or a string for the class attribute you were creating an entry in the instance namespace (because of the assignment statement), but when using a list you act directly on the class variable, which is indeed shared between all instances.

Comment: Excellent answer. I can't believe this isn't a mega-dupe.