# Python class and instance attributes memory usage

Tags: python, class, subclass

I have a class with some class attributes

```
class Test:
    attr = {#lots of data}


class Sub(Test):
    def __init__(self, param):
        self.param = param
```

Now if I initialize lots of subclasses `[Sub(i) for i in range(10000)]` each instance of `Sub` will have an attribute `attr`. Does that copy the data in `attr` 10000 times or does each reference of `attr` point to the same dictionary?

Edit:

Could someone also explain this behavior if `attr` is a class attribute and the data does not get copied, what exactly happens here

```
test1 = Sub(1)
test2 = Sub(2)
test1.attr == test2.attr. # True

test1.attr = {}
test1.attr == test2.attr  # False
```

I was expecting that assigning an empty dictionary to the `attr` in the instance would overwrite the reference to the class attribute for all instances but that is not the case

Comment: `attr` is class attribute. No copy is done when `Sub(i)` is created.

Comment: Gotcha, what happens when you overwrite the class attribute in the instance? It doesn't seem to affect the class attribute in other instances

Comment: When you overwrite the attribute of an instance it only affects that instance. If you update the attribute, eg `test1.attr['foo'] = 0`, then all instances see the update.

Comment: You could also confirm this using the following: `Sub(1).attr is Sub(1).attr  # (is True)` and `Sub(1).param is Sub(2).param  # (is False)`.

Comment: Check out [Is Python class variable static?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50688881/674039)

Comment: Thanks everyone for the info!